# Getting wrong datetime field value while retrieving date from DB using HIbernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datetime, timezone

I am using Hibernate 4.3.2. I want to store all my dates in **UTC** in database. I am able to store date in **UTC**. Now I am retrieving date from database using below method.

```
public void getLastActiveTimeAndCheckForIt(int pageId)
{
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyTable.class, "myTable");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("myTable.id", 1));
    MyTable row = (MyTable) criteria.uniqueResult();
    System.out.println(row.getUpdatedDateTime());
   //output : 2014-06-10 03:05:35.0 and actual date in database : 2014-06-10 08:35:35
}
```

As I mentioned I am getting different date in output which is stored in database. I am not getting reason why?
Some steps I did to configure UTC timezone.
**1.** `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`
**2.** `System.setProperty("user.timezone", "UTC");`
**3.** `I also set my database timezone in UTC.`

Comment: But the object contains the correct value? Maybe the failure happens in `System.out.println` respective the `toString()`-method of the date.

Comment: Hi @Smutje, Thanks but How to debug Object value ?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `System.out.println(row.getUpdatedDateTime());` and look which values `row` contains.

Comment: hi, I debug it..in map I am getting same value.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Timezone offset being added to your date object. Try the below code

```
DateFormat converter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss");
converter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
System.out.println(converter.format(row.getUpdatedDateTime()));
```

Comment: but why that offset added to Date object even after I set UTC timezone everywhere?

Comment: Oh..I read it the other way around. Your database value is having the timezone offset.(By seeing the output the timezone setting in DB is not reflecting) But in Java as you are setting Timezone as UTC, its correcting that offset and showing GMT time. I have edited the answer. Just setting the timezone to default to be on safer side.